# Can anyone tell me what this icon is for or from?

Tags: applications, google-apps

Can anyone tell me what this notification icon is from? [image]

Comment: After unlocking the screen do you not see a notification with this icon? Have you thoroughly checked your apps list?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. If the device is yours, then you should be able to unlock it and see which app from the notification panel following the mentioned question above. Otherwise, we don't and can't identify each app notification based on photos/screenshots anymore, especially if the device is not your own.

Answer (score -1):

It is from any fitness or health apps on your phone. They are notifying you because of info in the app.